# valgrind Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s) , does this indicate memory leak?

Tags: c++, c, valgrind

I am facing a memory leak problem in the code, while its running, the heap goes on increasing to maximum and i need to restart the service, I ran top command and see that the heap is increasing whenever im invoking a scenario in the service.

I ran the service with valgrind ,

```
valgrind  --log-file=log-feb19.txt --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes --track-origins=yes myservice
```

I donot see any definitely lost or possibly lost blocks while iam running the scenarios but i see a lot of Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s) errors.

Do these count for a memory leak?

Example of what i am getting:

```
==27278== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)

==27278==    at 0xC90D91E: xcsFreeMemFn (in /apps/opt/mqm/lib64/libmqmcs_r.so)
```

........

```
==27278==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation

==27278==    at 0x4A078B8: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:270)

==27278==    by 0xC90E32F: xcsGetMemFn (in /apps/opt/mqm/lib64/libmqmcs_r.so)
```

Can someone help.

Comment: have you found the correct answer? if it is, mark one as correct, please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [pinpointing "conditional jump or move depends on uninitialized value(s)" valgrind message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612447/pinpointing-conditional-jump-or-move-depends-on-uninitialized-values-valgrin)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, it means that you are accessing memory that hasn't been initialized:

```
int main()
{
     int unitialized;
     std::cout << unitialized << std::endl;
}
```

would trigger this error.

Slightly more common would be:

```
struct X 
{
     X() : i(42) { }
  private:
     int i;
     int* forgotten; // oops, not initialized
};
```

Lastly, this frequently happens with malloc based code, when you don't use `memset` to clear the whole buffer. So,

1. malloc a buffer size m
2. read (e.g. from a socket) n bytes
3. write m bytes to a file; (m-n) bytes wouldn't have been initialized

Comment: I agree this does not indicate a memory leak but as it invokes undefined behavior it may lead to anything

Comment: Actually, it is more than that, it means that the flow of execution of program might depend on an uninitialized value.

Answer (score 5):

It is explained in Valgrind User Manual, in section [4.2.2. Use of uninitialised values](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.uninitvals):

> An uninitialised-value use error is reported when your program uses a
>   value which hasn't been initialised -- in other words, is undefined.
>
> ...
>
> It is important to understand that your program can copy around
>   junk (uninitialised) data as much as it likes. Memcheck observes this
>   and keeps track of the data, but does not complain. A complaint is
>   issued only when your program attempts to make use of uninitialised
>   data in a way that might affect your program's externally-visible
>   behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

No this does not indicate memory leak directly. However having a conditional jump depending on a non-initialized variable may lead to practically anything. Using uninitialized variables in general invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: In C, using an uninitialized object is not undefined behavior per se. It is only UB if the object "could have been declared with `register`" that is if its address is never taken. Reading uninitialized memory through a pointer is perfectly fine (from that POV). It is the branching on such values that valgrind rightly complains about.