# Conditional jump or move error in valgrind

Tags: c

I am trying to use `valgrind` to detect memory errors. 
This is part of my code-

```
else
{
137.    printf("HELlo\n");  
138.    char * lexeme1;char * lexeme2;
139.    lexeme1=substr1(bufferOld,beginPointer,sizeBuffer-1);
140.    lexeme2=substr1(buffer,0,indexStart-1);
141.    strcat(lexeme,lexeme1);
142.    strcat(lexeme,lexeme2);
}

Token  getNextToken( int fp1, FILE * fp)
{
  ...
  207. lexeme=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
  ...
}
```

Upon running `valgrind` it gives me the following error-

```
==9720== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==9720==    at 0x4C2DD9A: strcat (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==9720==    by 0x401048: updateToken (lexer.c:141)
==9720==    by 0x402A92: getNextToken (lexer.c:498)
==9720==    by 0x400A17: main (driver.c:66)
==9720==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==9720==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==9720==    by 0x4012C6: getNextToken (lexer.c:207)
==9720==    by 0x400A17: main (driver.c:66)
==9720==
```

I am not sure why I am getting these kinds of error. Any help would be highly appreciated.

**Update-**

Here is my substr1 function-

```
char * substr1(char * source,int start,int end)
{

    char * dest=malloc((end-start+2)*sizeof(char));
    if(end==-1)
        return dest;
    int i,count=0;
    for(i=start;i<=end;i++)
        dest[count++]=source[i];
    dest[count]='\0';
    return dest;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612447/pinpointing-conditional-jump-or-move-depends-on-uninitialized-values-valgrin
and see if that helps?

Comment: Show us `substr1`.

Comment: @stackptr Updated my question. Please have a look.

Comment: In the posted fragments, you have allocated memory for `lexeme` but not initialised it as a C string so that it can be the object of `strcat`.

Comment: Also `if (end==-1)` case probably wants to set `dest[0]='\0';` before returning.

Comment: At what point are you `free`'ing `dest`?

Comment: @ryyker I am not `free`ing `dest`. Should that be causing this error?

Comment: @Noober NO, but that is  a problem too. You are using `strcat(lexeme,lexeme1);` and `leseme` is not initialized

Comment: Show us lines `66, 498` by the way The line `66` is inside driver.c =>> `driver.c:66`

Comment: @Michi Using `strcpy(lexeme,lexem1)` for the first time fixed the error. Thanks a lot. It seems `lexeme` was not initialized and that was causing the error.

Comment: Also, be sure to check the return value of `malloc`.

Comment: @Noober `strcat` allows one memory block to be appended to another memory block. Both memory blocks are required to be null-terminated in your case wasn't so, hence the need of `strcpy`, Remember that. Any way I'm not saying that the two Answers are wrong, but the problem with `calloc` is, that ends with too many `ZERO's`

Comment: in C, when calling `malloc()` 1) do not cast the returned value.  The return type is `void*` so can be assigned to any pointer.   Casting just clutters the code making it more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.  2) the expression: `sizeof( char)`  is defined in the standard as 1.  multiplying anything by 1 has no effect on the parameter passed to `malloc()`   Strongly suggest removing that expression.  3) when calling `malloc()` always check (!=NULL) to assure the operation was successful

Comment: regarding this line: `char * dest=malloc((end-start+2)*sizeof(char));`  with `end` having a possible value of -1 and start being at some offset into the char array,  the value passed to `malloc()` will be negative, (but malloc() assumes a positive parameter)  so a huge amount of memory will be allocated.  probably not what you want.   Suggest checking that `end` is greater than `start` before calling malloc()`

Comment: regarding this code block: `if(end==-1) return dest;`, this will return a pointer to uninitialized memory.  Probably not what you want.    If `malloc()` failed, then would be returning NULL,  given the other code, probably not what you want.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding by us humans: please follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These two lines

```
  strcat(lexeme,lexeme1);
  strcat(lexeme,lexeme2);
```

are concatenating onto `lexeme`, which in turn points to uninitialised memory, allocated here:

```
  lexeme=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
```

To fix this either initialise the memory explicitly by calling:

```
  memset(lexeme, 0, 100);
```

or implicitly by using `calloc()`  instead of `malloc()`:

```
  lexeme = calloc(100, 1);
```

**Update:**

A 3rd option, as mentioned by [*Michi*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4745612/michi) in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36163306/conditional-jump-or-move-error-in-valgrind/36163829#comment59964839_36163829) would be to replace the 1st call to `strcat()` by calling `strcpy()`

```
  strcpy(lexeme, lexeme1);
  strcat(lexeme, lexeme2);
```

This probably is the cheapest solution, at least in terms of speed.

---

In any case remove the useless cast to `(char*)` and replace `sizeof char` by `1` which it is by definition.

Comment: `strcpy` was missing there.

Comment: @Michi - if calloc is used to create the memory, then can a `strcat()` not be used as the very first copy?  (i.e. without first calling `strcpy`?)

Comment: @ryyker: Sure it can.

Comment: @ryyker That's the whole point, `strcat` needs `strcpy` if you are going to use `malloc`, if you don't use `strcpy` then, `calloc` is needed, because of `malloc` which will not initialize it for you..

Comment: `This probably is the cheapest solution, at least in terms of speed` I like this :))

Comment: @Michi - I think we are in agreement.  (it was a rhetorical question :) ) Thank you.

Comment: @ryyker Of course :). Any way when `strcpy` is used the `'\0'` is copied to, which means that if [the program was written well](http://ideone.com/CKLCPE), will be no need of [calloc](http://ideone.com/qy1V1n).

Answer (score 1):

As is shown by @Alk's answer (+1), the central problem is concatenating into uninitialized memory (needed to start with a creating memory, and initialization of `lexeme`).  But here are some additional suggestions for avoiding memory creation/use issues:

Because `sizeof(char);` is always 1, malloc statement can be written:

```
char * dest=malloc((end-start+2));
```

But because `malloc()` does not initialize  the memory it creates, and because of the nature of the problem you are seeing, I suggest two additional things:

*1)* check the values for *source*, *start* and *end* before using them in memory allocation statement.

*2)* use `calloc()` rather than `malloc()` as it will initialize all memory to a known value:

```
char * dest=calloc((end-start+2), 1);
```

Comment: The problem is with `lexeme`

Comment: @Michi - _lesne_?  I do not see it.

Comment: `strcpy` was only thing that he needed.

Comment: @Michi - LOL, yes people tell me that.  Thank you.

Comment: The problem with `strcat` is, that they need `strcpy` too. So to fix it they use `calloc` which is not wrong, but not entirely what they need.

Comment: `use calloc() rather than malloc()` if the dest string has, lets say `calloc(100, 1)` will be a lot of `ZERO'S` there, if source has length of `15`

Comment: @Michi - Yes true, but if source only needs 15, then `char * string = calloc(15, 1);` will work.  Also, since each location in memory is initialized with NULL terminator (using `calloc`), using `strcat` for very first call is OK.  For `malloc` it would not be.